# Angular 2: How to apply a callback when I leave a route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Here is the example, I have some routes defined in `AppComponent`:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/',         name: 'Index', component: IndexComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path:'/:id/...',  name: 'User',  component: UserComponent},
  {path:'/plan',     name: 'Plan',  component: PlanComponent},
  {path:'/foo',      name: 'Foo',   component: FooComponent}
]}
```

and in `UserComponent` I have another route defined like this :

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/info',   name: 'UserInfo',   component: UserInfoComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path:'/order',  name: 'UserOrder',  component: UserOrderComponent},
  {path:'/detail', name: 'UserDetail', component: UserDetailComponent}
]}
```

There are 2 separate navigations defined in both `AppComponent` and `UserComponent`:

```
//AppComponent:
  <a [routerLink]="['User']">User</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['Plan']">Plan</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['Foo']">Foo</a>
--------------------------------------------
//UserComponent:
  <a [routerLink]="['UserInfo']">User Info</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['UserOrder']">User Order</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['UserDetail']">User Detail</a>
```

The behavior I expect is:
When user click on these navigations, a modal will comes up and ask user if he confirm to save before leaving this route. if yes, save the user's change automatically.

Since it seems that there is no way to get these changes in `UserComponent`, I want to put the logic into these child components (`UserInfoComponent`, `UserOrderComponent` and `UserDetailComponent`). So is there any way I can trigger a callback when user leave the current route inside the child component? if not, is there any alternative way to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: can you just set a value (a "callback") upon entering the route, like `x.currentRouteLeave=function(){dostuff()}`? that way, you can call `someReachableObject.currentRouteLeave()` from the new route. i;ve used a similar pattern to track the last used textbox to apply shared editor buttons...

Comment: @dandavis, u mean have a custom router with the `currentRouteLeave` function?

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-candeactivate/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Router already comes with [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#lifecycle-hooks) , [CanDeactivate Interface](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanDeactivate-interface.html)

The hook to allow/deny navigating away is `routerCanDeactivate(nextInstruction, prevInstruction) { ... }`. It will stop the navigation if you return false from this function.

Example [With Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IY8lLF3i5ujtRpY14YZk?p=preview):  (in the plunker, route 2 will never allow navigating away. You cannot go back to route 1)

```
@Component({
  selector:'route-2',
  template:'route 2 template'
})
class SecondRoute{
  routerCanDeactivate(){
    return false; // false stops navigation, true continue navigation
  }
}
```

Comment: @ZhiLi You are welcome, the other router lifecycle hooks are very useful too